# psql not reading password from .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql

On running the command to connect to psql server it's prompting for password even though 
password and other details are there in the .pgpass file in the home directory as well as current
directory

```
 psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 postgres
 Password for user postgres:
```

These are the contents of .pgpass file : 
`127.0.0.1:5432:postgres:postgres:rohit` I am not sure why it still prompts for the password.

`-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   39 Apr  9 16:59 .pgpass`

Comment: I'd run `strace psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 postgres 2> out` and then check 'out' to see if it had attempted to open a .pgpass file.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I saw a permission denied error and changed the owner to my username and then it worked. Is this `strace` something general ? Could it be used with anything else ?

Comment: `man strace` and all will be revealed.